# Crash when accessing static variable exported with a def file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am using a def file to export some static functions and variables from a dll. When accessing the static variable after importing the dll the program crashes. Any ideas why this is happening? I am using VS2017, Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0.

library.h

```
struct DLLEXPORT A {
  static int a;
  static int get();
};

struct B {
  static int b;
  static int get();
};
```

library.cpp

```
int A::a = 0; 
int A::get() {return a;}

int B::b = 0;
int B::get() {return b;}
```

library.def

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS
  ?b@B@@2HA
  ?get@B@@SAHXZ
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
  int a = A::get(); // Works fine
  int b = B::get(); // Works fine

  A::a = 1; // Works fine
  B::b = 1; // CRASH (Access violation writing location ...)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to export also B::b;

Comment: @SHR It is exported in def file, isn't it? Otherwise OP would get unresolved external symbol linker error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think def file entry lacks `DATA` attribute so `B::b` is treated as code which is typically-read only:

```
?b@B@@2HA DATA
```